# In Josso, how to get the user details using the "josso_assertion_id"

Tags: java, josso

How to obtain the user credentials using the "josso_assertion_id" which is obtained after a successful login.

Are their any API calls to obtain the user credentials in JOSSO.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Krishna

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

after getting the `assertion_id`, you need to call the `SSOIdentityProvider` web service and the method `resolveAuthenticationAssertion`

It will give the `session_id` that refers to a user. You can then use this `session_id`to do any kind of requests to the web services

Have a look at http://josso_server_url/josso/services

to have the list of available services

Comment: After using the resolveAuthenticationAssertion method with the "josso_assertion_id" i get a message "Error dereferencing authentication assertion : "josso_assertion_id"" with the cause as org.josso.gateway.assertion.exceptions.AssertionNotValidException: Invalid JOSSO Authentication Assertion : "josso_assertion_id".